# Using value from the knockoutjs $data object as an index

Tags: knockout.js

I won't paste a fully working code here since it would take me a lot time to do it and I think this questions either has a concrete answer or not.

I have this very simple collection iteration:

```
'<tbody data-bind="foreach: ' + DynamicCollectionName + '">'
```

And inside this foreach I want to access another nested collection:

```
'<span>' + myViewModel.myCollection[<theIndex>].SomeValue + '</span>'
```

So I already have value for the `<theIndex>` which I can access like that:

```
'<span data-bind="text: $data.<theIndex>"></span>'
```

and on the page I can see `1, 2, 3...` the values that I need, but if I try something, at least natural to me, like:

```
myViewModel.myCollection[$data.<theIndex>].SomeValue
```

then I don't get errors in the console, but also don't get any data. I'm a huge `Knockout Js` newbie so if I miss some important information please ask. Basically if I could just `eval()` this it would do the trick, but maybe knockout has a different way of doing these things.

Comment: Are you looking for `$index()`? Inside the viewmodel, `$data` refers to the item at the current iteration index. I.e., in a `foreach` binding: `$parent[$index()] === $data`.

Comment: I found couple of ways to do my specific jobs. What bugs me is that I have access to the `$data.<theIndex>` value when it's binded so there should be a way to access it directly. At least it seems logical to me.

Comment: What is the server-side technology you're trying to mix in with your markup here? Is that an asp razor view?

Comment: It seems odd that you can access your data which you're calling an index by using dot notation. If it's an index then it should be part of a collection which you access with an indexer instead like `$data[<theIndex>]`